# What is the best way to add extensibility to the actions of a class in python

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I am writing a super-class that has the code to generate a context menu on right-clicking a particular button.

When I/others subclass this, I want it to be trivial to add actions to this context menu, and not have to worry about re-writing the whole method to draw it.

What is the smoothest oop way to go about this in python?

```
def context_menu(self, image_name, event):
    menu = Tk.Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
    menu.add_command(label="Copy Image Path", command= lambda name=image_name: self.to_clipboard(name))
    ## TODO add the ability to neatly add context options when defining a subclass.
    #for label, action in cls.context_options:
    #    menu.add(label=label, command=action(image_name))
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very basic way:

```
class AbstractMenu:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.menu = Tk.Menu(root, tearoff=0)

    def post(self, event):
        self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)


class BaseMenu(AbstractMenu):
    def __init__(self, root, image_name):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Copy Image Path", command= lambda name=image_name: self.to_clipboard(name))


class DerivedMenu(BaseMenu):
    def __init__(self, root, ...):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Another command" ...)
```

Usage:

```
menu=BaseMenu(root, imgname)
menu.post(event)
```

or:

```
menu=DerivedMenu(root, ...)
menu.post(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Then define your event_handlers which will simplify the process and call a method which would be overridden in the subclass.

For instance:

```
class Popup:
    def __init__ (self, ...):
        # Set the menu and bind handlers to events (particularly the left click to self.__on_click__())

    def __on_click__(self, event):
        # Something/nothing here
        self.OnClick(event)
        # Something/nothing here too

    # Event handler to be overridden
    def OnClick (self, event): pass

    # Or simply call handlers upon events directly if you don't need anything internal to happen.
```

Then just override a handler from a subclass, or you can do it even from outside:

```
# From outside:
def ActivateSomething (self, e):
    if e.GetId()==20: print "Option 1"
    else: print "Something else"
popup = Popup()
popup.OnClick = ActivateSomething

# Or, of course:
class MyPopup (Popup):
    def OnClick (self, e):
        if e.GetId()==20: print "Option 1"
        else: print "Something else"
```

NOTE: This is somewhat pseudocode-ic

I usually do it that way. Not only for menues, but it is useful for other GUI stuff.

E.g. If you are loading a big file and need a progress dialog, then do it with handlers and you may control how it'll be shown for different file formats. When will the dialog be updated for instance, or how will you manage canceling for different formats.